# Ransomware Type of Virus and How to prevent it (Zepto Virus)

Tags: ransomware

My computer had been hit by a Zepto virus which is a type of ransomware. All my files had been encrypted to a file that cannot be opened by any applications. It only hits all my office document files. I had to reformat my pc in order to erase it.

- Is there any applications or countermeasure in order to prevent it from happening again?
- If I don't have any file backup, is there any application that can remove zepto file extension?

P.S. I am not the only one who uses the computer so I cannot easily say that I can manage it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To prevent it from happening again, tip would be to follow the standard safe browsing best practices apart from trying to identify how this virus came to your machine in the first place.

Comment: @Limit Can you give me example of practices? thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not tech support for a malware removal forum. The duplicate will give you some guidance.

Comment: 1, yes, lots. 2. no, always backup anything you want